# Chinese Idiom puzzle 13 (中文填字遊戲)

Tags: idioms, games, puzzle

Please solve the following puzzle

[image]

1. A grain of rice in the sea. A metaphor for something small and insignificant
2. To bluff
3. Disappear without a trace, no news, or nothing to follow
4. Idiom
5. The multi-level gates are tightly locked. Describes that the protection and blockade are very tight
6. A metaphor for situations that makes people suspicious.
7. Elite newcomer
8. adopted son
9. A long time
10. Repay a favor
11. Male matchmaker
12. Never miss the target
13. Age 50
14. A long long time (like eternality)
15. Depend on others and cannot be independent
16. Self-taught
17. Expression doesn't change (doesn't seem to be affected or care)
18. Walking instead of riding transportation
19. Bicycle
20. Only change the form, but the content and essence stay the same
21. The gain does not compensate for the lost
22. A hermit's life
23. Ability to tolerate and forgive others
24. Time changes

A. Even the stubborn stones are convinced

B. You can see a person's appearance but you cannot see what is in his heart

C. A praise for 関羽

D. Melon seeds

E. Change the appearance completely

F. After a long time, things change beyond recognition

G. The plum tree was bitten by insects and died instead of the peach tree, which satirizes the brothers’ inability to help and love each other

H. The area between the nose and the upper lip

I. Time does not wait for us. Metaphor for missed the opportunity, regrets too late

J. Only under the top boss (above everyone else)

K. The title of heir of the kingship or lordship in ancient time

L. Have students all over the world

M. sleeping pill

N. dispute

O. Sincere and affectionate words

P. At the pinnacle of one's popularity and power

Q. Been through a long time

R. Waterwheel

S. 11:00 PM - 1:00 AM

T. Unintentional mistake

U. A battle-hardened elite army

V. Easy

W. Gain fame quickly

X. Did something wrong and now suffer the consequences (You asked for it)

Y. Having inner and outer beauty

Z. Extremely numerous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second version, corrected. Thank you~.

[image]

Comment: Good job! I have 重門深鎖 for  (5). Didn't know there's another similar idiom 重垣疊鎖 and I would accept it as a correct answer. (P) is 當時得令 and you forgot to fill in the character 時. (K) is 世子 (the title of heir); 世襲 is 'a system' (W) 聲名鵲起 not 鶴起. Correct them and I will accept your answer

Comment: I would accept 爭執，爭議，爭論，爭吵 for (N)

Comment: Thak your for correction.